# Passing an array of differently typed Action<T> to a method

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code, which stores a list of actions to perform based on the type of value passed as an argument...

```cs
Action<int> intAction = x => Console.WriteLine($"You sent an int: {x}");
Action<bool> boolAction = x => Console.WriteLine($"You sent a bool: {x}");

var funcsByInputType = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();
funcsByInputType[typeof(int)] = (object x) => intAction((int)x);
funcsByInputType[typeof(bool)] = (object x) => boolAction((bool)x);

PerformAction(true);
PerformAction(42);

void PerformAction<TValue>(TValue value)
{
    if (funcsByInputType!.TryGetValue(typeof(TValue), out Action<object>? action))
    {
        action(value!);
    }
}
```

This works as expected.

What I now want to do is create the dictionary from a single method that I only call once, so I can rewrite my code like this instead.

```cs
Action<int> intAction = x => Console.WriteLine($"You sent an int: {x}");
Action<bool> boolAction = x => Console.WriteLine($"You sent a bool: {x}");

funcsByInputType = MakeFuncsByInputType(intAction, boolAction);

PerformAction(true);
PerformAction(42);

void PerformAction<TValue>(TValue value)
{
    if (funcsByInputType!.TryGetValue(typeof(TValue), out Action<object>? action))
    {
        action(value!);
    }
}
```

How could I write the `MakeFuncsByInputType` method?

Note that I don't want to make multiple calls to the method, and I don't want to have my parameters defined as `params object[]`

Comment: If you want to make one call, I suggest reflection-based discovery that can use a pattern or a marker to indicate what should be selected. For example, I have a library that can automatically register `Parse` and `TryParse` methods for a type based on method signatures the first time a type is used, with the option to fall back on wrapping `Parse` in a try/catch if `TryParse` doesn't exist on the type. You would need to decide what the basis for discovery would be before the question could be answered.

Comment: Change signature of `MakeFuncsByInputType` to `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> MakeFuncsByInputType(params Func<(Type t, Action<object> a)>[] args)` and then define each arg similar to `Func<(Type, Action<object>)> intAction = () => (typeof(int), x => Console.WriteLine($"You sent an int: {(int)x}"));`

Comment: Why ` I don't want to have my parameters defined as params object[] ` ?

Comment: @timchang That's what i thought too but in Twitter exchange OP confirmed he did want `params` to be able to pass in any number of delegates. Changing to `Func` from `Action` allowed a working solution I could not post when question was closed. But i don't seem to understand the desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because via an `Action<object>` as an alias of `Action<string>` I would be able to pass `42` instead of a string.

So I had to go with a builder pattern instead.

public static partial class Reducer
{
public static Builder New() => new Builder();

```
public class Builder<TState>
{
    private bool Built;
    private ImmutableArray<KeyValuePair<Type, Func<TState, object, Result<TState>>>> TypesAndReducers;

    internal Builder() => TypesAndReducers = ImmutableArray.Create<KeyValuePair<Type, Func<TState, object, Result<TState>>>>();

    public Builder<TState> Add<TDelta>(Func<TState, TDelta, Result<TState>> reducer)
    {
        if (reducer is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reducer));

        EnsureNotBuilt();
        TypesAndReducers = TypesAndReducers.Add(new(typeof(TDelta), (state, delta) => reducer(state, (TDelta)delta)));
        return this;
    }

    public Func<TState, object, Result<TState>> Build()
    {
        EnsureNotBuilt();
        if (TypesAndReducers.Length == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Must add at least one reducer to build.");

        Built = true;

        var dictionary = TypesAndReducers
            .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(x => x.Value));

        return (TState state, object delta) =>
        {
            if (delta is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(delta));

            if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(delta.GetType(), out var reducers))
                return (false, state);

            bool anyChanged = false;
            TState newState = state;
            foreach(var reducer in reducers)
            {
                (bool changed, newState) = reducer(newState, delta);
                anyChanged |= changed;
            }

            return anyChanged
                ? (true, newState)
                : (false, state);
        };
    }

    private void EnsureNotBuilt()
    {
        if (Built)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Reducer has already been built.");
    }

}
```

}